# Django Object Filter (last 1000)

Tags: django, filter

How would one go about retrieving the last 1,000 values from a database via a Objects.filter? The one I am currently doing is bringing me the first 1,000 values to be entered into the database (i.e. 10,000 rows and it's bringing me the 1-1000, instead of 9000-1,000).

Current Code:

```
limit = 1000
Shop.objects.filter(ID = someArray[ID])[:limit]
```

Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Solution:

```
queryset = Shop.objects.filter(id=someArray[id])
limit = 1000
count = queryset.count()
endoflist = queryset.order_by('timestamp')[count-limit:]
```

`endoflist` is the queryset you want.

---

### Efficiency:

The following is from the django docs about the [reverse()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#reverse) queryset method.

> To retrieve the ''last'' five items in
>   a queryset, you could do this:
>
> ```
> my_queryset.reverse()[:5]
> ```
>
> Note that this is not quite the same
>   as slicing from the end of a sequence
>   in Python. The above example will
>   return the last item first, then the
>   penultimate item and so on. If we had
>   a Python sequence and looked at
>   seq[-5:], we would see the fifth-last
>   item first. Django doesn't support
>   that mode of access (slicing from the
>   end), because it's not possible to do
>   it efficiently in SQL.

So I'm not sure if my answer is merely inefficient, or extremely inefficient. I moved the `order_by` to the final query, but I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: Ahh! You're on the right track, my good man. However I need it to Descend. Therefore if it went 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and I wanted the last two.. I'd like it as "6,7" and not "7,6".

Comment: Then how about: `Shop.objects.filter(id=someArray[id]).reverse()[:limit].reverse()`

Comment: Doesn't work. That just reverts it back to the original list (first 1000 instead of last.

Comment: Good job! That works like a dream! Though is that the most efficient way? I'm not too sure how Django handles these calls, but aren't you originally searching for all IDs via timestamp and then doing the limit? As opposed to the original way which limits the original search?

Comment: I added a little bit to my answer about efficiency, but it's not really my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

```
reversed(Shop.objects.filter(id=someArray[id]).reverse()[:limit])
```